# Function callback in pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can do like this in jquery, but I never understand how it work in native JS.

```
function init(){

 return $.ajax({
 'type':POST,
 'url':'example.com'

})

init.success(function(data){
data
});
```

How can we write a callback in pure JS? so that I can use it this way :

```
myFunction('myparam',function(){
return 'this is myFunction callback';
}
```

Comment: [All you need to know is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: `function myFunction(param1, callback){/* ... */ if(typeof callback === "function") { callback(); }}`

Comment: @Andreas is callback() a built in function? to call the parent's function when execute?

Comment: It's just the name of the parameter which, when it is a function, is executed in the `if` branch.

Comment: @Andreas I see, so it can be any name?

Comment: The name is completley up to you. But if the callback has a specific purpose I would call it accordingly `success`/`onsucces`, `error`/`onerror`, `done`, ... With `callback` nearly every developer intantly knows that it's a parameter used to pass a function which will be executed as the last step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, a function can be passed to another function like every other argument. That functions can later use it, by invoking it whenever it needs.
This is very common for callback functions.

Example:

```
function checkName(name, callbackFn){
  if(name == "Alice"){
    callbackFn("Great Name!");
  }
  else {
    callbackFn("Wrong name");
  }
}
```

And the call can be:

```
checkName("Alice", function(message){
  alert(message);
});
```

This kind of programming is very useful for asynchronous tasks (like Ajax calls), since the handling function can invoke the callback function when the task is done.

Using callback functions is a method related to functional programming, where functions are passed between higher level functions as arguments. Another way to achieve this goal in the new JS spec (ES2015), is using [Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/), which can be resolved only when the task is done.

Comment: What is the main different btw callback and promises?

Comment: @AliceXu what is common between them? They are completely different concepts.

Comment: @AliceXu they can both be used for the same purpose (controlling asynchronous operations), but they represent two very different concepts.